# Mikrotik Website Whitelist

Tags: firewall

guys!

I'm noob to MikroTik's RouterBOARD and RouterOS and ended up finding it a bit confusing.

What I need is as simple as the title says: I need to create a website White-list; just that.

I need to be able to block **all websites** except those that are on the proposed White-list.

Thanks!

Comment: How many sites are on the white list?

Comment: About 10 websites. Thats why I found better to block all and only allow those 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the mikrotik wiki there are lot of examples on how to use the http proxy feature.
Anyway:
On the IP/Proxy menu you can set the options of the embedded http proxy: in the "*/ip proxy access*" part you can define you access policies in terms of http host names or ip addresses.

Then, you have two options to make it working as a trasparent proxy.
A fully trasparent proxy means that the users do not have to configure it in their browser.
http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/How_to_make_transparent_web_proxy

BUT, doing so, you cannot filter HTTPS protocol.

If you want to filter also https using your proxy, I can advise to use a "proxy auto-discover" mechanism, like WPAD.
http://findproxyforurl.com/wpad-introduction/

Is this enough to start?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the integrated HTTP proxy in transparent mode

Comment: You could improve your answer by editing it to add more details to make it more useful both for the original poster and future users. Typically short answers like this could provide reasonging why you believe this is the answer, more explanation about the concepts mentioned, references/links to supporting resources, or applicable examples.

Comment: Ok. Your answer is a bit vague. How do I use the HTTPProxy in Transparent Mode and where do I find it?
I've only found the Web Proxy...